# Parallel Block-Structured class abstraction for FDM

Tags: finite-difference, parallel-computing, computational-geometry, finite-volume

I’m currently developing a FDM/FVM (using contravariant coordinates) code using Fortran and Co-Arrays (SIMD, in general), and so far I have all sparse matrix (BiCGStab, working on AMG) solvers and data-structure (CCS) libaries developed and working (I think), but so far I haven’t come up with the correct abstraction for the mesh class and, by corollary, the fields and operators.

Said abstraction, I hope, could be a natural extension of a single-block structured mesh which may be treated using simple 2D or 3D (or ND) arrays. Indexing therefore would be natural (i,j,k) both for the fields and mesh nodes/centroids. Parallelization is “trivial” in this context. (Halo/ghost cells).

Clearly, on a multi-block structured mesh context, the natural (i,j,k) indexing cannot be used anymore unless you come up with a clever strategy on how to split the overall multiblock mesh onto smaller “rectangles” distributed across images. I guess one may come up with a “super-mesh” which just extends the computational gridlines up to the outermost boundaries, in order to be able to exploit (i,j,k) indexing. See below:

[image: Example Mesh (not mine)]

This idea, although KISS-like, seems to me quite “wasteful” since you may end up with super-grids orders of magnitude bigger than the original one, besides it requires you keep track of your “live/fake cells” making your DO loops inefficient, so I’m not so convinced on this route.

I guess the question is whether it is possible to manufacture a class for block-structured meshes that allows me to use (i,j,k) indexing. My reason for preferring (i,j,k) indexing, instead of more general face-ordering of data (unstructured codes) is that the former is more amenable for Pade-type schemes and translates directly to FDM. My other excuse is that I’m not familiar with graph-splitting (metis, etc) and data-structures for general unstructured (or block structured) codes, but I’m willing to learn if that’s the way to go. I might be wrong and perhaps there’s a more general data structure and graph partitioning that allows me to achieve good parallelization.

Anyway, if you guys may point me towards the correct direction/literature I’d be very grateful (:

Comment: Why would you spend the time to implement all of these data structures when there are excellent libraries out there that already do all of that?

Comment: May you suggest one, please?

Comment: Google @WolfgangBangerth .... :-)

Comment: For parallel linear algebra, check PETSc and Trilinos. For unstructured meshes, check p4est and PETSc. For parallel discretizations of PDEs, check deal.II (my own project) or libMesh. All of these projects have spent decades of work on providing pretty much anything you might ever want; they also all run on 10,000 and more processes.